# I need to make it verify the username by checking if its in the external text file

Tags: python

the issue is my method of checking the external file isn't working. pretty much all of this isn't working, its just a part of my game.

```
file = open("users.txt","w")
file.write("ali/n")
file.write("mike/n")
file.write("guy/n")
file.close()

def login():
  username = input ("enter username")
  **for line in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
   while username not in users.txt:**
    print("incorrect")
    username = input ("enter username  ")
  print ("correct")
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What result do you get? Does anything get printed at all? I think the reason you might not be getting expected results is that strings read from text file have '\n' in the end. And `while` statement may not execute

Comment: it comes up with an error due to the while part. if you could just suggest a different method to verify the username

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def login():
  username = input ("enter username")
  users = open("users.txt","r").readlines()
  users = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in users] # remove newline for each user in users
  while username not in users: # check if entered username is in text file
      print("incorrect")
      username = input ("enter username  ")
  print("correct")
```

Comment: without the /n it works but now there is no separation between usernames

Comment: @Ali, there is no separation where? In text file? You can keep names separated in text file, the code I suggested just removes newline characters from the strings in the array, to check if they match with entered string.

Comment: when i have /n after each username in the text file it does not work but when i make the file and leave out the /n e.g
file.write("ali") instead of
file.write("ali/n") it works but only if there is one name in the file

Comment: I dont know what you are doing incorrectly then, I tried this code myself and it works for me

Comment: it must be a problem with my first making of the file. Ill send it in my next comment

Comment: file = open("users.txt","w")
file.write("ali/n")
file.write("mike/n")
file.write("guy/n")
file.close()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def login():
    username = input("enter username  ")
    users = [x.strip() for x in open("users.txt","r").readlines()]
    while username not in users:
        print("incorrect")
        username = input("enter username  ")
    print ("correct 1")
```

Comment: it stil comes up with this error message                                                                          File "main.py", line 3
    users = open("users.txt","r").readlines():
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Whoops, I left the colon there. I fixed it now

Comment: the error is gone but it keeps printing incorrect even when the username is in the file